# Is there a way to clone/template linux VMs on Hyper-V

Tags: linux, virtualization, windows-server-2012-r2, virtual-machines, hyper-v

I've seen how you can do it with System Center but we don't have a System Center license and there is no plans to get one. I guess I could install a trial for the 60 days just for this purpose but I was curious if there was another way to do this.

In the past I've done powershell to copy the VHDX or VHD files and load in Hyper-V but that always seemed to break networking in a weird way which I guess has something to do with hardware finger printing and MACs?

Basically, I want to be able to build this Linux template with GRSecurity/SELinux that has been optimized for security and then spin up 30 different VMs off this template and install services on each of them and then manage them all with pupet/chef.

Just curious how you professions handle image cloning/templates and spinning them up.

Comment: `Just curious how you professions handle image cloning/templates and spinning them up.` By using the right tools, be it SCVMM at the hypervisor layer or some kind of CM at the OS layer.

Comment: For Windows virtual machines you could simply Sysprep them then export/import them in Hyper-V. You could certainly export/import a Linux virtual machine but I'm not sure how you would generalize them in order to make each one unique.

Comment: That is my problem. I've done Windows easy. I have entire scripts that do that. Linux not so much. My issue was on a copy I have to rebuild the entire eth0 device so it works correctly.